# sbt per-user settings in multi-project build

Tags: scala, sbt

How should I store per-user settings in sbt 1.0+ with a multi-project build? The way recommended in https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Best-Practices.html#local-settings doesn't work with a child project `build.sbt` like

```
val sshUser = settingKey[String]("SSH user")
val sshUser := "user"
```

and child project `local.sbt` like

```
sshUser := "synapse"
```

with the error `error: not found: value sshUser`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when using SBT 1.0+ I'd recommend to read the documentation corresponding to that version: [SBT 1.0 Best Practices](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Best-Practices.html). Your link leads to very old documentation for a long deprecated sbt version.

Still, the `local.sbt` is a valid one even in sbt 1.0. However, if you want to apply your setting to several or all projects in a multi project build, you need to tell SBT so:

```
ThisBuild / sshUser := "synapse"
```

See [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html). Otherwise, the setting is only applied to the root project.